# JQuery Mobile - Dynamically Adding Collapsible Divs Containing Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have developed a UI that dynamically adds collapsible divs by cloning a template element in the HTML. The div contains a radio button. The issue is that after the division has been cloned and added, the radio button does not function (the selected element cannot be altered).

The HTML for relevant section is below:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="appointments-list">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="appointment" id="appointment" unique-id="">
        <h1 id="appointment-heading"></h1>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="radio-group">
            <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
        </fieldset>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div>
                <textarea id="notes"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <button class="ui-button" id="appointment-save-button">Save</button>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <button class="ui-button" id="appointment-finalise-button">Finalise</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code cloning the collapsible is below:

```
function updateAppointment(elem_appointment, data_appointment, str_date)
{
var elem_appointment_new = $('#appointment').clone();

    addAppointment(elem_appointment_new, data_appointment, elem_appointment.attr('id'), str_date);
    elem_appointment_new.collapsible('expand');

    var radio_group = elem_appointment_new.find('#radio-group');

    radio_group.checkboxradio();
    radio_group.checkboxradio('refresh');

    elem_appointment.after(elem_appointment_new);
    elem_appointment.remove();
}
```

Note the cloned collapsible has all the functions called to make it work called on it in the function "addAppointment". A stripped down version of it is below:

```
function addAppointment(elem_appointment, data_appointment, id_appointment, str_date)
{
    elem_appointment.show();
    elem_appointment.attr('id', id_appointment);
    elem_appointment.attr('unique-id', data_appointment['ID']);

    elem_appointment.find('.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle').children().unwrap();
    elem_appointment.find('.ui-collapsible-heading-status').remove();
    elem_appointment.find('.ui-collapsible-content').children().unwrap();
    elem_appointment.collapsible();
}
```

When I try to press one of the radio buttons, I get the below error in my Javascript console in Chrome:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

Could anyone tell me how I can get the radio buttons to work?

Comment: which jQM version are you using? Edit: 1.4.3

Comment: It was 1.4.2. I ended up solving this problem with a workaround rather than a fix.